# How to use the newly added table from dnn default db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity, data-access-layer, dotnetnuke-7

I am developing a module using DAL2 C# compiled module, i have created a new table in default dnn db and added some values inside that,

Table name:

> [dnndev.me].[dbo].[testtab]

Now I want to use the values from that new table inside my module, can anyone knows how to call this new table?? [Should not use sql query]

Do I want to add any class for this?? [like entity or repository]

If yes, then how to add the class and use the function to call that??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check out.. https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com

The templates include a working module that accesses a table.

If you look into the components folder you will see an Item and ItemController Class.

This is a very good example of how to access a table using DAL2

Regards

James